# HttpsURLConnection isn't working in android studio

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I'm developing an application using android studio, I'm completely new to android and this is my second application, I've searched everywhere to find a way to open an url and to read the Json content from it, these are the codes i have found, but the problem is where it arrives to "con.connect();" it says Unfortunately your application has stopped working i can't read even the string from that url, i really don't know what the problem is, so i hope you can help me solving this problem.

```
public String webrequest(String url1){
    try {

        URL url = new URL(url1);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.connect();
        if (con != null) {
            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));
                String input;
                while ((input = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(input);
                }
                br.close();
                return input.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //return input;
    return "";
}
```

And by the way, i have got the internet permission in android manifest.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you run this code outside the main (UI) thread? Did you use AsyncTask or a similar thread oriented approach?

Answer (score 1):

Try this formate -

```
private InputStream openHttpConnection(String urlStr) {
  InputStream in = null;
  int resCode = -1;

  try {
     URL url = new URL(urlStr);
     URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();

     if (!(urlConn instanceof HttpURLConnection)) {
        throw new IOException("URL is not an Http URL");
     }
     HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) urlConn;
     httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
     httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
     httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
     httpConn.connect();
     resCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();

     if (resCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        in = httpConn.getInputStream();
     }
  }

  catch (MalformedURLException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }

  catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return in;
}
```

Comment: What about `HttpsURLConnection`?

Answer (score -3):

Add  useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy' in app build.gradle in android section.

As shown below:

```
android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.test.smapp"
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 23
        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            }
        }
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }
```

Comment: The OP wants to use HttpsURLConnection, please respect those intentions.